# localhost problem on windows 7

Tags: asp.net, configuration, windows-7, hosts, loopback

I'm using Windows 7 Pro and want to run my web project locally, but the url `www.localhost.com` does not work.

If use `http://127.0.0.1:2710/default.aspx` it works. I checked host file which in the `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc\hosts` folder. If I delete the rows:

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Nothing changes. How can I make www.localhost.com work on my machine?

Comment: Sorry - can't understand the question...

Comment: @DJ... For him the url is shown as www.localhost.com and he wants to see it as localhost.

Comment: The lines you deleted were comments.

Comment: Thanks Sinan, that threw me a bit, the markdown was not showing the lines as bold not comments... :(

Comment: There's no place like 127.0.0.1 (sorry, couldn't resist :)

Answer (score 5):

Hope I understand your question correct. You want to acces your local site using www.localhost.com

Just edit the hosts file and add the following lines

127.0.0.1   www.localhost.com

I checked my Windows 7 hosts file and it has the following lines

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Above lines are comments and deleting those lines does not do anything.

Note: If you get "**Access denied**" when you save the hosts file then open notepad as **Administrator** and then edit hosts file and save it. It should work

Comment: No. i want to acces my local site using http://localhost:2710/default.aspx. but when i run my project i see www.localhost.com in url.
my host file has
 # 127.0.0.1       localhost that row

Comment: alo.. does www.localhost.com work for you or yu are not able to see your site?

Comment: www.localhost.com replaces what you entered because some browsers will substitute common web prefixes and domains when the original address does not get resolved. For example, you type "anyweb" and that name cannot be found in DNS. Your browser automatically tries: "anyweb.com", "anyweb.net", and "www.anyweb.com". When it runs out of alternatives, it keeps the last thing it tried.
You can either turn this feature off to aid your debugging or simply recognize that when it happens, it means you entered an unknown address.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: The rows you deleted were just comments, so that doesn't matter.

Were you trying to enter your url just as [`localhost`](http://localhost)
or as [`http://localhost:2710/default.aspx`](http://localhost:2710/default.aspx)?
The latter is probably necessary, as the 2710 is the port number, and without it will default to port 80, which probably doesn't have anything listening on it.

---

**UPDATE:** It might actually be an IPv6 thing, so try it with just this line in your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

You should not have a `#` at the beginning of the line, that will disable that line.

(You might need to reboot too).

You could also try pinging localhost (just type `ping localhost` in a command prompt window) and check that you get a reply from 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Did you try: 
http://localhost:2710/default.aspx ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, simply put, your web project will run on http://localhost:2710/default.aspx, once you put those lines you removed back into the hosts file ([More on it here](http://accs-net.com/hosts/what_is_hosts.html)). To get to remove the port number, you need to reconfigure *your web server*.

Now, if you want to get a *domain*, that's a different thing altogether... then, you need to get a registrar and use DNS to get it to map to you. You would do this if you wanted other people to be able to use something like www.site.com to get to your site.

Comment: I think his browser was auto-correcting the word `localhost` for him